# select2 is not showing when the map is fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-select2

hey i was trying to show the select2(its backend) on google map and that worked but when the map is full screen then the lists are not showing.i tried by changing the z-index value but is not working.can anybody help me ??

```
    $('document').ready(function() {
    $('#Name').select2({
        placeholder: "Choose name",
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        ajax: {
            url: 'somthing here ...',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: $.trim(params.term)
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                // console.log(data);
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            },
            cache: true
        }
    });
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now your `select2 div` is outside of all div last element of body.

Pass **dropdownParent** with google map class so the `select2 div` will inside the that div.

check with the inspect element and then try to use z-index.

```
 $('#Name').select2({
        placeholder: "Choose name",
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        dropdownParent: $('.map'),
        ajax: {
            url: 'somthing here ...',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: $.trim(params.term)
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                // console.log(data);
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            },
            cache: true
        }
    });
```

Check more info : [common-problems](https://select2.org/troubleshooting/common-problems)

Answer (score 1):

I used @Diip's link. But for my case, when the map goes to fullscreen, I noticed that `$('.map')` does not show up. I changed to use dropdownParent with the map's element `gm-style` and wait until map loaded like this:

```
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function () {
        // do something only the first time the map is loaded
        selectTag.select2({
            width: '100%',
            placeholder: "Select an option",
            allowClear: true,
            dropdownParent: map_container_tag.find('.gm-style'), // attach to google map when fullscreen
        });
    });
```